# How to define where libs are loaded from

Tags: c++, gcc, aix

I am trying to compile omniORB on AIX 6.1 with gcc 4.2.0.

The initialization does not work as it is picking up the non pthreaded library.

If I set LIBPATH to /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/ omniNames will not work, as the streams interface gives an exception.

Setting the LIBPATH to /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/pthread seems to work, but other non pthreaded programs will pick up the pthreaded lib which may cause problems...

The link looks like this:

```
g++ -o omniNames -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -fexceptions -Wl,-brtl -Wl,-blibpath:/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/dbx/omniORB-4/lib -L../../../lib -L../../../../lib omniNames.o NamingContext_i.o log.o omniNamesWin.o -lomniORB4-ar -lomnithread34 -lpthreads
```

How do I resolve this ??

Note that I have tried to change libpath using configure arguments but without success.

Answer (score 2):

Launching via a wrapper script which set LIBPATH correctly is probably the easiest.

Then there is the RUNPATH/RPATH feature of ELF which allows to embded a search path for dynamic libraries in the executable; but I don't know if AIX implement it.  It it does and is set with the same argument as for Linux and Solaris, `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-R$(RUNPATH)` for DT_RUNPATH, `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,-R$(RPATH)` for DT_RPATH; you may want to test also simply `-Wl,-R$(RPATH)` (which will probably set the DT_RPATH).

Answer (score 2):

Each OS uses its own unique set of environment variables to decide where to search for shared libraries.

Most UNIX like systems use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (but it varies).

I found that the most effective way to find which environment variable to use is to look at the man page for dlopen() on the platform you are building for.

**Edited**: also note that these variables act like the PATH environment variables, in that they are a list of paths that are ':' separated. So could you not set the environment like this:

```
# Using  tcsh syntax for setting environment. Your shell may very.
setenv LIBPATH "/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/:/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix6.1.0.0/4.2.0/pthread"
```

Comment: AIX uses `LIBPATH` where SunOS and Linux use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and HP-UX use `SHLIB_PATH` (and then comes the complication of 32bit and 64bit versions).  My understanding of the OP problem is that if he set the LIBPATH to some value, it is incorrect for some programs, if he corrects it for those, it is now incorrect for other.

Answer (score 1):

The AIX `ld` man page states:

```
   Note: If you specify a shared object, or an archive file containing a
   shared object, with an absolute or relative path name, instead of with
   the -lName flag, the path name is included in the import file ID string
   in the loader section of the output file. You can override this
   behavior with the -bnoipath option.
```

So, just specifying /my/path/to/libfoo.so instead of `-lfoo` should give you the behaviour you want.